# How to update Partial View without full replacement

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this partial view.  This works, ie, when the user clicks the button, an ajax trip is made to the server, and it updates the partial view and it comes down and replaces the current div with the updated Div and shows the Promo Message.

However, it seems there should be a better way to do this.  In other words, is it necessary to replace the entire partial view?  Isn't there a way to send just the data up to the server, and then update just the message when it gets back, like maybe via a JSON call?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ApplyPromoCode(OrderViewModel orderViewModel) {
        orderViewModel.PromoMessage = "Promo has been applied";
        return PartialView("PromoPartial", orderViewModel);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
    @model NTC.PropertySearch.Models.OrderViewModel
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ApplyPromoCode", "OrderSummary", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode =     InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "promo" }))
    {
        <div id="promo">
        <table>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PromoCode)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PromoCode)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PromoCode)
        </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Apply Promo Code" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.PromoMessage)
            </td>
    </table>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this to

Controller

```
public ActionResult ApplyPromoCode(OrderViewModel orderViewModel) {
        //your processing code
        return Content("Promo has been applied");
    }
```

View

```
 @model NTC.PropertySearch.Models.OrderViewModel
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ApplyPromoCode", "OrderSummary", new AjaxOptions {  UpdateTargetId = "pcode" }))
    {
        <div id="promo">
        <table>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PromoCode)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PromoCode)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PromoCode)
        </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Apply Promo Code" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="pcode"></div>
            </td>
    </table>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I think its a nice and simple approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a PartialView you can always return a JSON object/array or some XML and use jQuery/JavaScript on your callback function to update the values of your input fields.

Here's an example of some code I use to return JSON from a Controller:

```
public ActionResult CurrentTags(int entityID)
{
        Entity entity = db.Entity.Find(entityID);
        var tags = from tag in entity.Tag
                   select new
                   {
                       id = tag.Name,
                       text = tag.Name
                   };
        return this.Json(tags, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Can you give me an example of what the view looks like as well?

Comment: You just need to get rid of the ajax form, making it a normal form and on the document ready (assuming you are using jquery) bind its submit event to a js function that ajax submit the form and then display the result, in your case the "Promo has been applied" message.

Comment: This code was used in a different scenario which consisted of getting the available tags for an autocomplete box and was just an example for returning JSON from the controller. You don't really need the Ajax.BeginForm(), like @Maess said, as you can just bind an event to the button and then it's a matter of, within the callback function, finding the element you want to update and use the ajax response's data to update it.